# Rails how to serve .pde asset files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, processing, assets

I have in my .html file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "processing-1.4.1.min" %>
<canvas data-processing-sources="/assets/pjs/my.pde"></canvas>
```

and the asset lies exactly there: `app/assets/pjs/my.pde`.

I get this error in the server:

```
Served asset /pjs/my.pde - 404 Not Found (10ms)
```

and this error in the javascript:

```
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: /assets/pjs/my.pde ==> Invalid XHR status 404
```

My application.rb says:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Might be a really stupid mistake but i just don't get it. I'd really appreciate if anyone can tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the erb extension for your view file, then use `asset_path 'my.pde'`.  When using the asset pipeline you can't link directly to a path because files will have fingerprints added to them.

Comment: Thanks. I changed `index.html` to `index.html.erb"` and changed the canvas line to: `<canvas data-processing-sources=<%= asset_path 'my.pde'%>></canvas>`. Now it works :-)